# phpMyAdmin login failure since upgrading

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've just upgraded to phpMyAdmin 3.5.7 and I can't login. When I try, I don't get an error but I'm returned to the login page with my 'admin' username gibbled (I think it's a character set issue but don't know how to fix it); attached is a screenshot of what's happening:

[image: PMA Screenshot]

Anyway any advice would be great!

PS When I say upgraded, I simply mean clean installed a higher version (ie it's a fresh configuration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had to do with the file-based session handler and the fact that I have multiple servers behind my load balancer. I changed my NGINX config to forward PMA to the primary server for now but I'll just change it to a MySQL session handler when I get around to it.

Comment: i need help regarding this issue,. i am unable to login to my phpmyadmin . credentials are inncorect.. from where i get those credentials

Comment: That's not the same issue. Your credentials would likely be provided by your hosting provider.

Comment: i solve the issue by re-installing the WAMP server. it works effcient,, Thankks for your kind reply. @Chelsea

Comment: if your password is ''  (I mean nothing) , then you cannot login after upgrading . In the case you have to update config.inc.php file in your phpMyAdmin. You need to  set allownopassword to ture